# Nokogiri gem very slow on simple request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to use Nokogiri to scrape a little bit of information from Amazon.

For some reason it takes about 50 seconds for this process to complete.  Am I doing something wrong that is making the code inefficient, or is that just how long it would take?

```
url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/" + item["ASIN"]
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
@numreviews = page.css('#averageCustomerReviews > a').text
```

I have this in a loop that does this to twenty different URLs.  Is there anyway to speed this up, or is it just that the pages it has to load to get the information will take that long?

Comment: Nokogiri isn't what is slow, since it doesn't retrieve the page. OpenURI retrieves it, which you don't show in your code sample. You can tell this because Nokogiri doesn't have an `open` method but OpenURI does. It's important to learn how your code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be because the response of this URL is too big. You can use the Amazon API which will give you selected information in XML, which will be easy to parse as well.

Comment: that is what I wanted to do, but the amazon api does not provide the number of customer reviews.  Is there a way to only load part of a page using this?

Comment: Just checked, Amazon API provides an iframe of reviews, by scraping this you can get reviews or number of reviews as well.

looking at this link:- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingCustomerReviews.html

Comment: Hey David, Please let me know if you are successful in getting the reviews, or the way by which you get those.

Comment: sorry fell asleep and forgot to respond.  i did use the iframe and scrape there.  that page has significantly less info and is much quicker.